# Merging list of maps with the same keys to one entry but with other fields are not the same

Tags: groovy

I need some help converting this current list of mine:

```
List data = [
    [name: "product1", category: "tshirt", color: "white", hex: "ffffff"],
    [name: "product1", category: "tshirt", color: "black", hex: "000000"],
    [name: "product2", category: "shoes", color: "white", hex: "ffffff"],
    [name: "product2", category: "shoes", color: "black", hex: "000000"],
]
```

To this:

```
List convertedData = [
    [name: "product1", category: "tshirt", colors: [ [color: "white", hex: "fffff"], [color: "black", hex: "000000"] ]],
    [name: "product2", category: "shoes", colors: [ [color: "white", hex: "fffff"], [color: "black", hex: "000000"] ]]
]
```

I did try using groupBy but did not succeed in achieving the same output as above and it is has already so much loop that it is not good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using groupBy is no bad idea.  You can just group by name and category and then collect over the groups.  E.g.:

```
def data = [[name: "product1", category: "tshirt", color: "white", hex: "ffffff"],
     [name: "product1", category: "tshirt", color: "black", hex: "000000"],
     [name: "product2", category: "shoes", color: "white", hex: "ffffff"],
     [name: "product2", category: "shoes", color: "black", hex: "000000"],]

println data.groupBy{
    it.subMap(["name","category"])
}.collect{
    it.key + [colors: it.value*.subMap(["color","hex"])]}

// [[name:product1, category:tshirt, colors:[
//  [color:white, hex:ffffff], [color:black, hex:000000]]], 
// [name:product2, category:shoes, colors:[
//  [color:white, hex:ffffff], [color:black, hex:000000]]]]
```

Comment: OMG it works! Can you explain the submap thing and the collect if possible? Also, about that it.value*.subMap thing. I don't get what's the purpose of the * . Thanks so much @cfrick.

Comment: subMap you can look up in the GDK for Map http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html.  `*.` is the spread operator. look that up in the groovy doc http://groovy-lang.org/single-page-documentation.html